# Adding a close button to a DIV that was appended on .click

Tags: jquery, append

I have been working on some jQuery code for an interactive map.  I've already gotten some fantastic help from a user named "Kevin Gurney" on here, so big thanks to him.   I'm now having another little issue, and was wondering if someone could advise.

Basically, when a user clicks on a point on my map, a DIV is appended with a full description of that map point.  I want to add a closing "X" icon in the top right of this DIV, so that the user can close it, however it seems that the first click event is stopping my second click event from working.

Here is [some sample of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/qw2v5/):

```
$(".point").live("mouseenter", function() {
    //code to show description
    $(this).append('<div class="mapitem-smalldescription">Small description</div>');
});

$(".point").live("mouseleave", function() {
    //code to show description
    $(".mapitem-smalldescription").fadeOut("normal", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
$(".point").live("click", function() {
    //code to full description
    $(this).append('<div class="mapitem-fulldescription"><div class="close">x</div>Full description</div>');

});

$(".close").live("click", function() {
    //code to close description, dosent work
    $(".mapitem-fulldescription").fadeOut("normal", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Click on one of the squares, the hover event is seperate. then click on the X at the top right side and nothing happens!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for [event.stopPropagation();](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(".close").live("click", function(event) {
    //code to close description, dosent work
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".mapitem-fulldescription").fadeOut("normal", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/qw2v5/4/).

Comment: @Stephen: Your fiddle is better than the post you commented on. +1

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by changing one of your functions slightly.

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/qw2v5/3/

Comment: I didn't negative vote you.   This code seems to work ok.  Thanks :)